# What is the correct way to do this? Initialization/Symbol not found errors

Tags: java, compiler-errors, initialization, java.util.scanner

I've been practicing with Scanner and exceptions and they're fairly new so maybe I'm missing something here:

This first way the compiler says it cannot find filename or f.

```
do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter the file name:  ");
                String filename = k.nextLine();
                Scanner f = new Scanner(new File(filename));
                done = true;
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException ex1){
                System.out.println("The file "+filename+" does not exist.");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Unpredicted exception");
            }
        } while (!done);
```

I thought I'd put it outside to fix it, but this other way it complains f and filename may have not been initialized

```
Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in), f;
        String filename;
        boolean done = false;
// Request file from the user
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter the file name:  ");
                filename = k.nextLine();
                f = new Scanner(new File(filename));
                done = true;
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException ex1){
                System.out.println("The file "+filename+" does not exist.");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Unpredicted exception");
            }
        } while (!done);
```

Comment: Consider changing your title to better reflect what you are trying to accomplish. As it is now, the title is a bit vague.

Comment: What would you recommend? I honestly thought the same, but I'm not even sure what's wrong so unsure what to specify...

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure either. Once the problem is solved it might be more clear. Even then changing the title would be benefitial for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise the value of filename to null. That way, if the catch block is entered, it will still have a value to use when you're printing the error message.

```
String filename = null;
```

Comment: Erm ... it sort of works.  But now you have to worry about what happens if `filename` is `null` when you come to print the message.  It should be OK in this case, but in other cases it won't be.

Answer (score 1):

You must always declare and initialize variables in such conditions before the 'try' block starts. Otherwise you will have to face with these errors:
'Cannot find the symbol' , 
'Variable not initialized' .

In your code you have declared the String variable outside the 'try' block which is fine, but the problem is that you have not initialized it. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Nit: 'Cannot find symbol' errors are not related to variable initialization; that's another problem.

Comment: 'Cannot find symbol' is encountered when even declaration is inside try block. 'Variable not initialized' when you initialize variable inside try block.

Comment: agreed! i should have elaborated more!

Answer (score 1):

A variable's scope is the block in which it's declared. Your first version declared `filename` in the `try` block, but you were trying to use it in the `catch` block (which is a *different* block despite being part of the one `try-catch` syntactical structure.

Your second attempt fixes this by declaring the variable with a scope that includes all places it is used, however in java local variables have no default initialization value; you must provide a value if there are code paths that could lead to accessing the variable *before* it has had a value assigned to it.

The fix is to provide any value (including `null`) to the variable before the `try-catch`., either at declaration time, or in the lines immediately following the declaration.